# How to get the indices of values in a list which are NOT an specific integer?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I got a real array `A`, where `Dimensions[A] == {5000, 5000, 5}`.

Some of the values in `A` are `-1`, others are not.

How can I use `Position[]` to find the indices of those values which are **not** `-1`?

Comment: It is easy to Position[A,-1] all the indices which are -1. How to find all other indices ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
A = Table[If[Round@# == -1, -1, #] &[RandomReal[{-2, 0}]], {5}, {5}]

{{-1, -1.85034, -0.063618, -1.97166, -1.98232},
 {-1, -0.407057, -1.72254, -1.5231, -1.99315},
 {-1, -1, -1, -1.98979, -1},
 {-1, -1, -0.134094, -1.92523, -1.90799},
 {-0.304344, -1, -1, -1.91487, -1.66092}}

SparseArray[A, Automatic, -1]["NonzeroPositions"]

{{1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {1,5}, {2,2}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {2,5}, {3,4}, {4,3}, {4,4}, {4,5}, {5,1}, {5,4}, {5,5}}
```

Comment: Error message of an example: "Part specification \!\(\"NonzeroPositions\"\) is neither a \
machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers"

Comment: `"NonzeroPositions"` is a function argument, not a part. Did you use double brackets instead of single?

Comment: It works! thanks

Comment: That's the one to use. +1

Answer (score 3):

`Position[A, Except[-1], {-1}, Heads -> False]`

Comment: It does not work for the code "Position[{1, 2, -1, 3}, Except[-1], {2}, Heads -> False]"

Comment: I assumed A was two dimensional, like you said in the question. Fortunately it's easy to fix; see edited answer.

Comment: I would assume A to be any dimensional array /list. This should also be an answer. How can I accept both them?

Comment: @LCFactorization when you say the word Matrix in your question `I got a real matrix A`, it implies 2D matrix. A list such as {1,2,3} is not a matrix. Matrix is rectangular. Always. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29

Comment: I agree. thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 0):

Below the code will be OK . thanks

```
 Position[Boole[(# != -1) & /@ A], 1];
```

Comment: The above does not work. Try `A = Table[If[Round@# == -1, -1, #] &[RandomReal[{-2, 0}]], {5}, {5}];
Position[Boole[(# != -1) & /@ A], 1]`