# Finding elements from a sparse matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I am dealing sparse matrices of very large dimensions. I need to locate the positive and negative elements of the matrices and make lists of their corresponding positions. Of course I can write a program which scans every element and gives the output. But is it possible to do it in a neater way? for instance, to make a list of `1`'s, 
I used `Position[S,1]`, but in future I need to get a list of positions of all entries which are `>0` for example.

As suggested, I am giving an example of one of the smallest lists.  For instance, I want to make a list of positions of elements which are `>0`.

```
S={{1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},      
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0},       
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},       
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0},      
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},       
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},         
   {-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1}};
```

Comment: @Öskå I have added one small example of $S$.

Comment: Related: [(31908)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31908/121), [(37691)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37691/121), [(19910)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19910/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at `Unitize`, `UnitStep`, `Clip`, `Sign`, etc. and the `NonzeroPositions` property of sparse arrays. Using these in combination with appropriate arithmetic operations you can quickly get positions.

You could also take a look at `FilterRules`, and use this against the array rules to get positions for specified elements.

With your updated post, e.g., elements >0:

```
SparseArray[UnitStep[Sign[S] - 1]]["NonzeroPositions"]

(*
{{1, 1}, {1, 5}, {5, 1}, {5, 5}, {10, 10}, {10, 14}, {10, 18}, {14, 
  10}, {14, 14}, {14, 18}, {18, 10}, {18, 14}, {18, 18}, {19, 
  19}, {19, 23}, {19, 27}, {23, 19}, {23, 23}, {23, 27}, {27, 
  19}, {27, 23}, {27, 27}}
*)
```

Using `FilterRules`:

```
   FilterRules[Reverse /@ ArrayRules[S], ele_ /; ele > 0][[All, 2]]

  (*
  {{1, 1}, {1, 5}, {5, 1}, {5, 5}, {10, 10}, {10, 14}, {10, 18}, {14, 
  10}, {14, 14}, {14, 18}, {18, 10}, {18, 14}, {18, 18}, {19, 
  19}, {19, 23}, {19, 27}, {23, 19}, {23, 23}, {23, 27}, {27, 
  19}, {27, 23}, {27, 27}}
  *)
```

If you're going to be doing various such searches on a given array, get the reversed rules once and use that result in the `FilterRules` to save time.

Comment: nice and concise +1

Answer (score 9):

This is reasonably fast and straightforward:

```
SparseArray[Positive@S, Automatic, False]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

**Update:**  Hmm, this slight modification of [rasher's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher) method is even faster on regular arrays:

```
SparseArray[1 - UnitStep[-S]]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

---

Timing comparison.  The array is about 90% zeros, 5% positive, 5% negative.

```
Table[
   foo = RandomChoice[{0.9, 0.05, 0.05} -> {0, -2, 2}, {10^k, 100}];
   {SparseArray[UnitStep[Sign[foo] - 1]]["NonzeroPositions"]        // timeAvg,
    SparseArray[Positive@foo, Automatic, False]["NonzeroPositions"] // timeAvg,
    SparseArray[1 - UnitStep[-foo]]["NonzeroPositions"]             // timeAvg},
   {k, 3, 6}
 ] ~Prepend~ {"Sign", "Positive", "-foo"} // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If `foo` or `S` is already a `SparseArray`, then [rasher's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher) `Sign` method is a bit faster than `Positive`.  Oddly, the `"-foo"` method is now slowest.

```
Table[
   foo = SparseArray[
     RandomChoice[{0.9, 0.05, 0.05} -> {0, -2, 2}, {10^k, 100}]];
   {SparseArray[UnitStep[Sign[foo] - 1]]["NonzeroPositions"]        // timeAvg,
    SparseArray[Positive@foo, Automatic, False]["NonzeroPositions"] // timeAvg,
    SparseArray[1 - UnitStep[-foo]]["NonzeroPositions"]             // timeAvg}},
   {k, 3, 6}
 ] ~Prepend~ {"Sign", "Positive", "-foo"} // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The timing function goes back to stackoverflow and [Timo and Mr.Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/4199042#4199042).

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@  AbsoluteTiming@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}];
```

Comment: @MichaelE2 ...very instructive...thanks +1

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example that uses properties of `SparseArray`. A small test array is used to illustrate. `positive` gives the positions of positive values in the sparse array and `negative` gives the positions of the negative values in the sparse array. These can be sa = extracts using `Extract[sa,positive]` etc.

```
SparseArray[
  Thread[RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {100, 2}] -> 
    RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 100]], {100, 100}];
position = sa["NonzeroPositions"];
values = sa["NonzeroValues"];
positive = Extract[position, pst = Position[values, _?Positive]];
negative = 
  Extract[position, Complement[List /@ Range[Length[values]], pst]];
```

The random 100 x 100 sparse array is created. The values and positions of non-zero values extracted then positive values collected and complement is negative values.

There are a number of ways to do this.

Comment: Nice examples, as always! +1