# Find positions where two matrices differ

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering

I have two matrices `A` and `B` of identical dimensions. What's the simplest (shortest) way to find the indices of differing elements?

Comment: related: [43938](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43938/5478)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've failed to find a duplicate so:

```
SparseArray[A - B]["NonzeroPositions"]

Position[A - B, x_ /; x != 0., {2}]
```

I hope those are numeric matrices, if not then you have to watch out on the `Condition` in the second solution.